# button color changed but not updated in screen in android

Tags: android-runonuithread

See I have used `runOnUIThread(){}` in `AsyncTask` to update button color. After updating those button attributes I can read its color, name, etc... In Log everything is showing correctly but those properties were not getting updated in UI. How to fix it?

Here is my code,

```
MainActivity.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
  @Override
   public void run() {
      Log.d("status","Inside Main Thread");
      Log.d("status","Chaning to your turn");
      yourTurn.setText("your turn *");
      oppTurn.setText("");
      Log.d("status","Your turn : " + yourTurn.getText().toString());
      Log.d("status","Your turn boolean : " + isYourTurn);
      Log.d("status","Changing bg color");
      button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
      Log.d("status","Updating the scores");
      yourScoreView.setText(gamer.getGamerName() + " Score : " + gamer.getYourScore());
      oppScoreView.setText(gamer.getOppName() + " Score : " + gamer.getOppScore());
    }
});
```